# Setting up a custom directive in angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

So I am fairly new to angular and I am trying to create a custom directive. I have found two great tutorials but the implementation I am trying to go for is different from the tutorials I used.

My HTML is as follows:

```
<!-- More HTML -->
 <ul>
  <display-evaluation></display-evaluation>
 </ul>
```

My template to be used by display-evaluation is as follows:

```
 <li>
   <div><p ng-model="eval">value to listen to</p></div>
 </li>
```

My controller looks like the following:

```
 .controller('mycontroller', function(){
    //a bunch of stuff
    this.showColor = red;
 })
```

My custom directive looks like the following:

```
 .directive('displayEvaluation', function(){
    return:{
       restrict:'E',
       templateUrl:'/path/to/template.html',
       require:'ngModel',
       replace: true,
       link: function(){
         //respond to changes in the p element
       }
    }
 })
```

So i am trying to listen to the p element in the template but the problem is i can not detect the changes to that element. Can any one help with probably suggesting how i can get to listen to these changes. Is my code properly structured for me to be able to do that.

Comment: First of all you dont use directives like that. ngModel doesn't work. ng-model does. Moreover there is no use of using ng-model with a p tag because ng-model is a 2 way binding. You can use ng-bind for that.

Comment: Apart from that you have used eval in your ng-model, but in your controller you don't have anything such as $scope.eval?? Seems you are not familiar with the basics itself. I would suggest that before getting into developing custom directives, you understand how angular provided directives work. You should know how ng-model, ng-bind, ng-show, ng-hide etc work.

Comment: Thank you @VinodBhavnani i will take more time in trying to understand the basics more.